# Guid additional column is always the same

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a Copy-Data task where I am adding an additional column called "Id" and its value is @guid(). Problem is that for every row it is importing, the Guid value is always the same and the destination/sink throws a primary key violation.

[Additional column definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrGQs.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copy activity will copy the same `guid()` for all rows if you use additional column.

To get Unique guid() for Each row, you can follow the demonstration below.

First Give your source data to lookup activity and give its output to a ForEach activity.

This is my source data in csv format for sample, give this to lookup.

**source.csv:**

```
name
"Rakesh"
"Laddu"
"Virat"
"John"
```

Use another dummy dataset and give any one value to it. Use this in copy activity.

**Dummy.csv:**

```
name
"Rakesh"
```

**ForEach activity:**

[image]

Inside ForEach use Copy activity and give the dummy dataset. Create additional columns and give our source data(`@item().name`) and `@guid()`.

**Copy activity:**

[image]

Now in sink give your database dataset. Here for sample, I have used Azure SQL database table.

Go to **mapping** of copy activity and click on `import Schemas`.Give any string value for it to import the schemas of source (Here dummy schema) and sink.

[image]

After the above, you will get like this, in this give the additional columns we created to the database columns.

[image]

**Pipeline Execution:**

[image]

After Executing the pipeline, you can get the desired output with Unique rows.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to make it work following your very detailed example.